# Convexity gap of a standard Gaussian function $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ i.e, $f((1-\alpha)x_1+\alpha x_2)-(1-\alpha) f(x_1)-\alpha f(x_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, convex-analysis

I am interested in finding a good lower bound on 
\begin{align}
f((1-\alpha)x_1+\alpha x_2)-(1-\alpha) f(x_1)-\alpha f(x_2) 
\end{align}
for $\alpha\in [0,1]$  where $f(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

Note, that $f(x)$ is concave for $ x \in [-1,1]$ and otherwise convex.

So, if $x_1,x_2 \in [-1,1]$ then
\begin{align}
f((1-\alpha)x_1+\alpha x_2)-(1-\alpha) f(x_1)-\alpha f(x_2)\ge 0,  
\end{align}

and

if $x_1,x_2 \neq [-1,1]$ then
\begin{align}
f((1-\alpha)x_1+\alpha x_2)-(1-\alpha) f(x_1)-\alpha f(x_2)\le 0,  
\end{align}

My question is whether we can derive sharper bounds for all $x_1,x_2$ of the form

\begin{align}
f((1-\alpha)x_1+\alpha x_2)-(1-\alpha) f(x_1)-\alpha f(x_2)\le g(\alpha,x_1,x_2),  
\end{align}
for some function $g$.

I am specifically, interested in the upper bound on the difference. 
This feels like something that must have been done before, but my search did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

(edit: now that the question has changed to allow a function on the right hand side, the below is less applicable)

Unless there are stronger conditions on $x_1$ and $x_2$, probably some bound on their difference, we can't strengthen the right hand side, except to say that it can't be $0$ unless $x_1 = x_2$. This is because $f(x)$ is continuous, and so taking $x_1 \to x_2$ we have $$f((1-\alpha)x_1 + \alpha x_2) \to f((1-\alpha)x_2 + \alpha x_2) = f(x_2)$$and $$(1-\alpha)f(x_1) + \alpha f(x_2) \to (1-\alpha)f(x_2) + \alpha f(x_2) = f(x_2)$$
so the left hand side of your inequalities is exactly $0$.

Comment: Yeah, I edit my question after you posted your answer. It seem that I did ask the question in best possible way.